# Given 3x nxn matrices A,B,C. Can i easily find entry [i,j] of product?

Tags: linear-algebra, products

I am reading my Linear Algebra book, and one of the exercises is asking me to find the entry (2,2) of a product of 3 3x3 matrices ABC without calculating the full product.

My current approach would be to:

1. Calculate (1,2),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,2) of AB
2. Then use that result to calculate (2,2) of (AB)C

Is this the fastest approach?

Comment: That's a strange collection of entries from $AB$ that you've calculated

Comment: Arg yeah sorry, i realized i only needed to calculate row 2, and not (1,2) and (3,2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** If $e_2 = (0,1,0)^T$, then the $2,2$ entry of our product can be written as
$$
e_2^T (ABC)e_2 = [(e_2^TA)B](Ce_2)
$$